# Getting IO privileges in Linux

Tags: linux, fedora, permissions, terminal, io

I have installed `flashrom` software. When i try to run `sudo flashrom` command it gives me "Could not get I/O privileges (Operation not permitted). You need to be root" error. Also I tried `su` command to switch root and run again. I also tried `sudo -i` command to login as root. However any of them did not work

Comment: Do you have sudo installed? Does it work for other commands? Can you `sudo ls` for example? How about `sudo -i`?

Comment: Yes I have sudo installed. Also i tried to run `su` to login as root however it does not give privilege.

Comment: But does `sudo` work ok for other commands? Can you `sudo -i` which is not the same as `su`?

Comment: `sudo -i` did not give any output. But as expected `sudo ls` lists my files in current directory

Comment: `sudo -i` gave no output but did _not_ log you in as root? Strange. Are you the administrator of this machine? Can you post your `/etc/sudoers` file?

Comment: sorry it logs me as root. I'm administrator.

Comment: Well, if it logs you in as root, try `sudo -i` and then run `flashrom`.

Comment: I'm still getting same error

Comment: OK, please [edit] your question and explain that i) other commands work as expected with `sudo`; ii) you _can_ switch to root using `su` but get the same error; iii) you also tried `sudo -i` and that also gives the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I changed secure boot option in bios settings as disabled. So I can run the flashrom program. But it gives this output.

> WARNING! You seem to be running flashrom on an unsupported laptop.
>   Laptops, notebooks and netbooks are difficult to support and we
>   recommend to use the vendor flashing utility. The embedded controller
>   (EC) in these machines often interacts badly with flashing. See the
>   manpage and http://www.flashrom.org/Laptops for details.
>
> If flash is shared with the EC, erase is guaranteed to brick your
>   laptop and write may brick your laptop. Read and probe may irritate
>   your EC and cause fan failure, backlight failure and sudden poweroff.
>   You have been warned.

So there is nothing to do. I have to search another tool to flash my bios